# Files which are greater than 2 MB in size are not uploading on server

Tags: android, image-uploading

In my application I need to implement uploading images, Text files zip folders and Pdf file. Every thing is fine for img\txt\zip\pdf but when I am selecting a file greater than 2 mb in size, it is not uploaded. following is my code.

```
public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) 
{
    try
    {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy= new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        String fileName = sourceFileUri;
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;  
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
        File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri); 

        if (!sourceFile.isFile()) 
        {
            title=filename+"";
            generateNotification(title, "Upload Failed..File Not Found");
        }
        else
        {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            String upLoadServerUri = "http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:xx/phpwebservice/upload.php";
            URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
            // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", filename); 

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""+ filename + "\"" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);;

            // create a buffer of  maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

            while (bytesRead > 0) 
            {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   
            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

            if(serverResponseCode == 200)
            {
                status = true;
            }
            else
            {
                title=filename+"";
                generateNotification(title, "File Not Uploaded");
            }

            //close the streams //
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
        }
    }
    catch (final MalformedURLException ext) 
    {
        title=filename+"";
        generateNotification(title, "File Not Uploaded");           
    }
    catch (final Exception etx) 
    {
        title=filename+"";
        generateNotification(title, "File Not Uploaded");
    }
    //dialog.dismiss();
    return serverResponseCode;
}
```

Please provide a solution for:

- how to upload Files greater than 2Mb with this method?

My PHP Side web service code is :

```
<?php
     $file_path = "a/";
     $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
     if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) 
    {
      echo "success";
    }
    else
    {
      echo "fail";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Problem might be on server side. Check the permissions on server.

Comment: For pdf files try to add `dos.writeBytes("Content-Type: application/pdf" + lineEnd);` after the Content-Disposition line. The 2 MB max upload limit you have to adjust at the webserver side.

Comment: Try to do search in your PDF file (open it as text in some editor), maybe it contains symbols "*****" inside it, so server threats this part of file as the end.

Comment: Thanks OleG For replying but soultion not worked for me. I dint find those symbbls

Comment: Thanks @greenapps I added that line but not worked. For permission how to check and edit settings\permission on php web server.

Comment: OK guys i tried to edit php.ini file and there i set upload_max_filesize = 100M;php_value post_max_size =0 by doing this now greater than 2MB files are getting saved.. Thanks @deepu513 and greenapps for suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer for size related problem by updating php.ini it works for me 
I had changed in my php.ini at two place

1. `upload_max_filesize = 4M`
2. `post_max_size = 0`

And after changing this setting my pdf files are also getting saved